# How do I set focus on a div after using window.location.href?

Tags: javascript

I want to set focus on a `div` after using `window.location.href`... how do I that? I tried the code below, but it only functions on `window.location.href` it doesn't focus on the specific `div`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   window.location.href="web_manage.php";

   $(function(){
      $("#tab2").focus();
   });

</script>
```

Comment: How does one "focus" on a `<div>`?

Comment: After you set `window.location.href`, the Javascript afterwards will not run regardless of what its intended purpose was, because you will have navigated away from the current page.

Comment: It can't focus on *anything* since the user's on a different page by then.

Comment: you have to do that on the page you're redirecting to.

Comment: If you want commands to run after `web_manage.php` has loaded, you will have to modify `web_manage.php` to take either `GET` or `POST` arguments, which will then cause it to generate `JS` or `HTML` to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
window.location.href="web_manage.php#tab2";
```

But that requires the receiving page (updating the `window.location` will *always* load a new page) to implement a means of showing that element based on its `id`, the hash, being present in the URL.

Perhaps with CSS:

```
#tab2:target {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

Or with jQuery (since you're using it already):

```
$('#' + document.location.hash).show();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , the code below

```
window.location.href="web_manage.php";
```

will not work as you will be navigated to another page.

And similarly .focus() will not work for div.

If you want to focus that particular div, then in the another page use the following code

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#tab2').offset().top }, 'slow');
```